# Trying to extend Ubuntu partition. Can't boot Ubuntu from USB. Already have Windows 8 and Ubuntu installed.

Tags: 16.04

I've ran out of space on my Ubuntu partition, so I want to extend it. I read that I can't do this through Windows 8 (my other installed OS) and I can't extend the partition while it's being used. I read that I should just run Ubuntu from a flash drive and use gparted to extend the partition, but I can't seem to boot from USB. When I start my computer I am greeted with the option to boot Windows or Ubuntu, but no option to boot from USB. USB booting is enabled from my bios and in Windows recognizes the USB drive as ubuntu

Comment: Please add to your question whether you use Legacy or UEFI

Comment: Before you reach option to select Ubuntu or Windows you have to press escape, or F2 or F12 depending on your BIOS to get your boot order menu. Then select boot from USB.